# How to get second word

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    First
    <p></p>
    Second
    <p></p>
    Third
</div>
```

How can I get the word `Second` in this case?

Comment: In what context? What are you using? XPath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) along with [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
var second = $('.test').contents().filter(function() {
                 return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
             }).eq(1).text();
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yhQYH/)</kbd>